# Autosar Trigger Ports for Software Components - How to trigger

Tags: triggers, configuration, autosar

How do I trigger the trigger ports, I have managed to create a SWC with the help of a developer tool, the swc has two trigger ports as input ports and the out ports are Sender ports.

If I wanted to trigger these Trigger ports, how would I trigger them?

(Edit:- Probably that needs creation of Trigger source, now how would I create a trigger source, what is an example of a trigger source?)

Comment: Do you mean, you are creating a software test-bench and you'd like to simulate the event firings of the RTE?

Comment: I have my drivers initialized in CAN, I am trying to create a software component generate rte ,bsw and flash it onto a hardware and check if the software works. I am not able to generate rte because the swc has trigger ports and I don't know how  would one trigger a trigger port

Answer (score 0):

You need to model an `ExternalTriggeringPoint` in one `RunnableEntity`. The `ExternalTriggeringPoint` shall reference a `Trigger` in the context of the `PortPrototype`.

Execution of the contract phase yields the availability of one `Rte_Trigger()` API that you can use to trigger a remote `RunnableEntity` at run-time.

Comment: I have triggering point defined in my runnable, all I need is to create a trigger and reference the trigger to the triggering point in the runnable

Comment: It's the other way round, as mentioned in my answer.